# Проблема импорта товаров из 1с в ручном режиме (через файл bx_1c_import.php)

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой импорта товаров в битрикс (версия 16.0.13). 
На сайте уже сформирована структура разделов и залиты товары, мне нужно обновить товары , делаю я это как написано в название темы через скрипт bx_1c_import.php процесс импорта идет нормально , ошибок не выдает. Настройки импорта на сайте

- Что делать с товарами, отсутствующими в файле импорта: деактивировать,
- Что делать с группами, отсутствующими в файле импорта: ничего 
  стоит галочка: Использовать контрольные суммы элементов для оптимизации обновления каталога 
  Время БД и сервера совпадают

Но после импорта абсолютно все товары деактивированы. А если я меняю настройку "Что делать с товарами, отсутствующими в файле импорта" с деактивировать на нечего то после импорта все товары активны. Проверил файлы выгрузки те товары которые деактивируются присутствуют в файле. Почему так может происходить ?

Comment: Товары сопоставляются по XML_ID?

Comment: Да, XML_ID товара совпадает с внешним кодом товара. Где - то на форумах битрикса вычитал примерно такую вещь:
Если делается полный импорт , то игнорируются настройки обмена на сайте и товаров которых нет в выгрузке становятся не активными.

Comment: Еще заметил такую вещь символьный код инфоблока куда идет импорт catalog-d116ca69-f5dd-4af3-a232-519304897f94 , а в файле выгрузки d116ca69-f5dd-4af3-a232-519304897f94 они должны быть абсолютно одинаковыми ? или приставка catalog- не играет роли ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С 4 версии обмена поддержка флагов «Что делать с товарами, отсутствующими в файле импорта» не используются, точнее могут использоваться, но работать при полной выгрузке может некорректно. В связи с тем что в полной выгрузке это не работало, и обмен происходит пакетами — лучше не использовать данный функционал.

Принято после обмена удалять товары лишние или в 1С помечать их и на сайте удалять.

Comment: т.е если будет делать выгрузку по изменениям то деактивации товаров не будет? тогда получается в ручном режиме нужно ставить "нечего" не делать с товарами ?

Comment: Дективироваться товары не должны — этот флаг должен пропускаться. То что у Вас сейчас деактивируются все это баг версии.

Comment: «тогда получается в ручном режиме нужно ставить "нечего" не делать с товарами ?» Верно

Comment: баг самого битрикса т.е конкретно моей версии 16.0.13 я все правильно понял ?

Comment: Да. В дальнейшем при обновлении до других версий могут наблюдаться другие баги — поэтому лучше просто не использовать этот параметр. Ничего не делайте и тогда всё будет работать стабильно) Глупо конечно, но сейчас же переход осуществляется к пакетному обмену — по несколько сотен/тысяч товаров для предотвращения падений. А запомнить какие товары выгружались, изменялись на каждом из шагов получается накладно поэтому этот функционал выпиливают.

Comment: По идее летом будет доступен новый модуль обмена и битрикс 16,5 выйдет и там уже этого не должно быть(деактивации)

Comment: но получается не нужные товары будут висеть в каталоге? как можно все таки их деактивировать ?

Comment: все понял , вы писали выше "Принято после обмена удалять товары лишние или в 1С помечать их и на сайте удалять."

Comment: Я говорю о удалении на стороне сайта по собственным настройкам — например поиск и удаление товаров, которые не изменялись месяц и их нет в наличии

Comment: Понял, спасибо =)